# delete an object using resource by id

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-resource

I want to delete an object selected by id, but when I press "delete" all objects are removed.

If I specify `Inventory.drop({id: 2}` it works, but using `Inventory.drop({id: '@id'})` it doesn't. Why?

```
$scope.deleteInv = function () {
    Inventory.drop();
 };
```

My template:

```
<td><a href="" ng-click="deleteInv()">X</a></td>
```

Here is my factory:

```
app.factory('Inventory', function($resource, $http) {
return $resource('http://someweb.com/api/v1/inventory/:id', {id: '@id'},
    {
        update: {
            method: 'POST',
            params: {id: '@id'},
            isArray: false
        },
        save: {
            method: 'PUT'
        },
        query: {
            method: 'GET',
            params: {id: '@id'},
            isArray: false
        },
        create: {
            method: 'POST'
        },
        drop: {
            method: 'DELETE',
            params: {id: '@id'}
        }
    }
);
});
```

Comment: I don't understand, where does the id should come from? You do not send the param when calling `Inventory.drop()`

Comment: shouldn't it get from `$resource` ? `{id: '@id'}`?? How can i declare id for Inventory?

Comment: Could you create a simple plunker? I guess that your `update` and `query` are working?

Comment: there is much stuff, dont know where to start, what kind of information do you need ? And yes query works, create works

Comment: in html: examples calling update, and drop. In js: a simplified Ctrl with your main scope variables. and of course Inventory.

Answer (score 0):

Because your @id is undefined.

Where you assign values for that? I think you does't.

So you need to change that

```
params: {id: $scope.YourId}
```

and you need to should be pass any values for `$sope.YourId`

and also You need define `$sope` in your factory `app.factory('Inventory', function($resource, $http,**$scope**) {`

Comment: something like this ? `params: {id: $scope.info.id}`? but it shows error that $scope not defined

Comment: Yes, You need define that here`app.factory('Inventory',` `function($resource, $http,**$scope**) {`

Comment: It shows that unknown symbol * and if i remove those ** ** in console i get `Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- Inventory`